# Java LibGDX: Tiledmap not rendering at the top and right side

Tags: java, libgdx, viewport

I'm trying to get a tiledmap to render over the whole screen. The problem is that the top or right 100px, everything is just black there. My tiledmap is around 100 tiles, so it should be able to render more than what it renders.

This is how it looks right now:
[image: my game right now]

1: This bar is expected as I do, currently, not have anything to render there.

2 & 3: These bars are unexpected as there are more parts of my tiledmap to render there.

I've already tried changing my Viewport from StretchViewport to FitViewport as well as FillViewport, but that doesn't change anything.

Here's my constructor in the PlayScreen class:

```
    public Play(GameStateManager gsm) {
       super(gsm);

       //set up box2d
       world = new World(new Vector2(0, -20.81f), true);
       cl = new MyContactListener();
       world.setContactListener(cl);
       b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

       //set up viewport
       vw = new StretchViewport(1280, 720, cam);
       cam.update();

       //create player
       createPlayer();

       //create tiles
       createTiles();

       //setup box2D cam
       b2dCam = new OrthographicCamera();
       b2dCam.setToOrtho(false, Game.V_WIDTH / PPM, Game.V_HEIGHT / PPM);
    }
```

Here's my createTiles() method:

```
    private void createTiles(){
        loader = new TmxMapLoader();

        tileMap = loader.load("data/lvl1.tmx");
        tmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap);
        cam.update();

        //get the size of the tiles
        tileSize = tileMap.getProperties().get("tilewidth", Integer.class);

        //create box2d bodies for all tiledmap layers
        TiledMapTileLayer layer;

        layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("red");
        createLayer(layer, B2DVars.BIT_RED);

        layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("orange");
        createLayer(layer, B2DVars.BIT_ORANGE);

        layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("yellow");
        createLayer(layer, B2DVars.BIT_YELLOW);

        layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("green");
        createLayer(layer, B2DVars.BIT_GREEN);

        layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("blue");
        createLayer(layer, B2DVars.BIT_BLUE);

        layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tileMap.getLayers().get("pink");
        createLayer(layer, B2DVars.BIT_PINK);
    }
```

The render() method:

```
    public void render(float delta) {
     //clear screen
     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.619607843f, 0.79607843137f, 1, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     //set cam to follow player
     cam.position.set(
          player.getPosition().x * PPM + Game.V_WIDTH / 4,
          Game.V_HEIGHT / 2, 
          0
     );

     //draw tile map
     tmr.setView(cam);
     tmr.render();

     //draw player
     sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
     player.render(sb);

     //draw box2d world
     b2dr.render(world, b2dCam.combined);

     //responsive resizing
     resize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

And here's the create() method inside my main game class:

```
    public void create () {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new MyInputProcessor());

    //asset managing
    res = new Content();
    res.loadTexture("data/player/player.png", "player");

    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);
    hudCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    hudCam.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);
    gsm = new GameStateManager(this);
}
```

I did not expect this game to get those black bars, I've created other games before and they have never gotten those. How can I remove them (2 & 3 on the image)?

Comment: Where `cam` comes from? For what you need an extra `OrthographicCamera` for Box2d? Where is the render() method? Can you show more of your code, please?

Comment: @Morchul I've added more code now, and the reason I have a separate OrthographicCamera is because the width and height of the Box2d cam is divided by my ppm variable, which is set to 100. Cam comes from the main game class. I might have kind of found the fix, which is to change my viewport to the screen size like this: resize(1280, 720) to resize(screenwidth, screenheight). But on screen resolutions like 1366x768, some of the pixels will be rendered double times then, probably because of stretch viewport.